# OpenLayers DrawFeature undo() and redo() functions

Tags: openlayers, undo, redo

I need to implement `undo` and `redo` functions in my app. I found that the simpliest way(?) is to use openlayers `undo` and `redo` build-in functions. -> http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DrawFeature-js.html

But I have troubles with implementing them. Can anybody provide me with an example of their implementation(`OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature.undo`) or give advice how can I implement `undo` and `redo` functions in another way?

Answer (score 3):

Have you take a look at its corresponding example?

See [Undo/Redo Drawing](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/draw-undo-redo.html) example.